# Cast to a Metatype Type in Swift?

Tags: swift

Can you cast to a Metatype Type in Swift? It really seems like you should be able to (after all you can instantiate objects from Metatypes).

The following doesn't work:

```
class Super {}

class A : Super {}

let superA:Super = A()
let subType = superA.dynamicType
let afterCast = superA as subType 

//Compiler error: "use of undeclared type 'subType'"
```

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

**Edit:**

As newacct pointed out, the result of .dynamicType is obviously not known until runtime, so a compile-time cast to the result of .dynamicType would not make sense.

So the answer is: "You can't" (and there is no good reason to try).

Comment: I guess you simply can't do that. The `let` creates an instance, not a type.

Comment: Sorry, which `let`? You mean `let subType = superA.dynamicType` creates an instance? So there is no way of accessing the type itself (actually instantiating a Metatype)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would be useful?

Comment: It's part of a complicated attempt to downcast to a protocol in one of the various situations where you can't use the @objc tag. If it's simply not possible in the language I'd like to know so I can try to think of something different. The official docs on Metatype types are very sparse so I wanted to ask.

Comment: Seems like a code smell that could be solved by casting to a Protocol - encouraging duck typing. Hard to know for sure without more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `as` takes a type, not an expression, on the right-hand side. So what you have is a syntax error.

What you seem to be trying to do is "cast" to a type that is computed at runtime. What would that even mean? Let's first consider what is a "cast".

Usually, when we have a cast expression `x as T`, it has two components:

- At compile-time: The entire cast expression `x as T` has compile-time type `T?`, which allows you to do stuff with the resulting expression that you maybe cannot do on `x` directly. In other words, it allows you to change the compile-time type.
- At runtime: It checks whether the runtime type of `x` is a subtype of `T`, and if it is, it evaluates to the optional containing that value, otherwise, it evaluates to `nil`.

If the type `T` is not known at compile-time, then obviously you cannot do the compile-time part of it. (The compile-time type of the resulting expression cannot, obviously, depend on something which is not known at compile-time.)

The other part, the runtime component, could that be done with a type computed at runtime? Sure. For example,

```
import Foundation
let afterCast : Super? =
    (superA as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(subType) ? superA : nil
```

It's not clear if that is what you want.

Comment: Okay, I see why you wouldn't be able to perform compile-time checks on a result from dynamicType. So you're right, the answer is essentially "No."

Comment: Minor detail: Referring to your first sentence, isn't a Metatype expression supposed to act like a Type? I'm slightly confused about why it is a syntax error

Comment: @thekwiat: An expression of metatype type or whatever type is still an expression. Expressions are used in different places syntactically than types.

Comment: Okay, thanks. For future reference, is there a way to extract the actual 'type' from a 'metatype'? I suppose this must happen implicitly when you instantiate an object from a metatype...

Comment: @thekwiat: I am not sure how you are using your terminology but I think there is a little confusion. In your program, you have a variable, `subType`, whose value is a type. The type of the variable `subType` is a metatype (type of a type). But `subType` itself, I would say, *is* a type. So you are "casting to a type", not "casting to a metatype" as your title suggests.

Comment: I see what you mean. But the title would have looked silly if you just remove "Metatype" haha