# Get a type of variable and declare an other variable with this type in Swift

Tags: json, swift, reflection, types

I currently exploring the JSON world in swift and I've some trouble to make a clean code.

Let's say I've the following structure

```
struct Foo {
  var a: String = ""
  var b: Int = 0
}
```

I use reflection to get a dictionary of the label : value of this struct with this function:

```
static func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String : AnyObject] {
  var dictionnary = [String : AnyObject]()

  for child in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
    dictionnary[child.label!] = child.value as AnyObject
  }

  return dictionnary
}
```

Now I have a dictionary of `[String : AnyObject]` and here comes the issue.

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
class JSONManager {

class func decode<T>(fromData data: Data) -> [T]? where T : JSONModelProtocol {
  let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,
                                                   options: [])

  guard let jsonDictionary = jsonObject as? [AnyObject] else {
    return nil
  }

  guard let json = jsonDictionary as? [[String : Any]] else {
    return nil
  }

  let representation = T.dictionaryRepresentation()
  for jsonItem in json { // json is a dictionary [String : Any]
    for (label, value) in object {
      let type = Mirror.init(reflecting: value).subjectType // The type of the item
      // Same whit let type = type(of: value)
      let item = jsonItem[label] as? type // This line doesn't work I cannot cast here
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: [Casting to meta type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882049/cast-to-a-metatype-type-in-swift) never worked in Swift

Comment: Swift is a Statically-Typed language, which means that variable types *must* be known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your replies. To bad we cannot do something clean like this in Swift I wanted to avoid the switch statement to find the right type.

Comment: What are you trying to solve by converting `Foo` to a dictionary?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I'm trying to implement a json decoder like this:
`decode<T>(fromData data: Data) -> [T]? where T : JSONModelProtocol`
I created many struct that are the models of the possible json results and conform to the JSONModelProtocol. For instance `Struct Book: JSONModelProtocol { var title = "", var author = ""}`
I was hoping to create a decoder that would give me a model object automatically like `let aBookStruct = JSONManager.Decode(fromData: dataOfABook)`

Comment: What you want is built into Swift 4's `Codable` protocol. Take a look [here](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375)

Comment: Yes thank you, I knew it but since it was for an app release I wanted to be able to do some code supporting iOs 9 or 10 at least. `Codable` is only available on iOs 11 unfortunately

Comment: @DEADBEEF, _Codable is only available on iOs 11 unfortunately_ Have you actually checked? The `Codable` feature is a part of Swift Standard Library and all needed codes are statically linked into your app binary, which runs on all devices where Swift is supported. Apple's doc marks `JSONDecoder` (and some other classes) as **iOS 7+**, and I have confirmed a simple sample code using `Codable` runs on the actual device of iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: @OOPer that's amazing! Thank you for you comment I didn't know that! You made my day!